# Libgdx: library not showing up on autocomplete even after successful build?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, libgdx

I'm using Android studio and I want to add a graph library to my libgdx desktop app. I followed the instructions on the libgdx docs and added the library to my root `build.gradle` file like so:

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-core
        compile group: 'org.jgrapht', name: 'jgrapht-core', version: '1.1.0'


    }
}
```

and ran "rebuild project", which returned a successful build. But the library doesn't show up on my autocomplete and is presumably missing.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What has this to do with Android and Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. All "mavenized repositories" need to be thrown under `project("core")`, like so:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile group: 'org.jgrapht', name: 'jgrapht-core', version: '0.9.0'

    }
}
```